# Lambda as a combination of methods from the Predicate interface doesn't compile if it is written as one statement

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8, currying

What is the difference between both these ways of lambda creation? Why doesn't the first one compile?

```
Predicate<Integer> predicate = Predicate.isEqual(0).or(Predicate.isEqual(1));
```

Gives:
**error**: incompatible types: `Predicate<Object>` cannot be converted to `Predicate<Integer> = Predicate.isEqual(0).or(Predicate.isEqual(1));`

```
Predicate<Integer> pred21 = Predicate.isEqual(0);
Predicate<Integer> pred22 = pred21.or(Predicate.isEqual(1));
```

This one works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding `<Integer>` before the `isEqual` method call should help :

```
Predicate<Integer> predicate = Predicate.<Integer>isEqual(0).or(Predicate.isEqual(1));
```

The reason behind such compiler behavior:

- `isEqual` is a static generic method which returns `Predicate<T>` (no matter what actual type of its input parameter is), so it returns `Predicate<Object>` when calling the method without specifying returning type explicitly.
- `or` is also a static generic method, but it returns a predicate parametrized by the same type, as its input parameter (which is `Predicate<Object>`).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is related to the way which the inference works in Java : it depends on the target.

Here :

```
Predicate<Integer> predicate = Predicate.isEqual(0)
                                        .or(Predicate.isEqual(1));
```

The type returned by `or(Predicate.isEqual(1))` depends on the type returned by `Predicate.isEqual(0)` (the nearest target) but this invocation doesn't specify any other type as return.
So `Object` is returned by `or(Predicate.isEqual(1))` as the method `isEqual()` defines `T` as return type without any wildcard :

```
static <T> Predicate<T> isEqual(Object targetRef) {
```

To solve your issue you indeed need to specify the return type of the first invocation in order to allow the chained invocation to infer the correct type : `Integer`.

```
Predicate<Integer> predicate = Predicate.<Integer>isEqual(0)
                                        .or(Predicate.isEqual(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because

```
Predicate.isEqual(0)
```

has this signature:

```
static <T> Predicate<T> isEqual(Object targetRef)
```

It infer `Predicate<Object>` if you don't type it.

To type it you can type the return type

```
Predicate<Integer> pred21 = Predicate.isEqual(0);
```

Or type the call like

```
Preicate.<Integer>isEqual
```

Comment: `It cast the Predicate to a Predicate<Object> if you don't type it.` well not exactly *casting*, but instead *inferring*

Answer (score 1):

Look at the signature:

```
 static <T> Predicate<T>    isEqual​(Object targetRef)
```

In the first example, the compiler cannot guess the generic type parameter, so it returns a `Predicate<Object>`.

The correct way to type it in one line would be to specify the type parameter like

```
Predicate<Integer> predicate = Predicate.<Integer>isEqual(0).or(Predicate.isEqual(1));
```